# Making a pushpin move along a route

Tags: c#-4.0, bing-maps, wpf-4.0

I have been searching for a answer for a, so it seems, rather specific problem. I've tried google, stackoverflow and to an extent, the microsoft forums.

For a school project I'm building a track and trace application, for an imaginary milk processing company. Some of the features it is supposed to have is that it can keep record of all the trucks, show a map of the area and show the state of the truck, it's whereabouts and it's freight. All the data is provided using a MySQL database.

I already managed to create a route and show it on my map using the code provided here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d7b0b272-35f3-4724-8546-dce9bd8b1e3d/wpf-bing-map-control-how-to-draw-route-lines?forum=bingmapssilverlightwpfcontrols

Now the problem is, I'd like to make it possible to let a pushpin move along a route, from start to end. For example, I create a route from Liverpool to Manchester, a blue line will show up on the map. The idea is that I create a pushpin ontop of Liverpool and make it move along the line all the way until it reaches Manchester.

I figured the best solution is to use a thread or timer that will change/update the location, using an event that fires?, of the pushpin, but I simply do not know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related blog post from the Bing Maps team: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bingdevcenter/archive/2014/04/07/staying-fit-with-bing-maps.aspx

Here are the basic idea of how to accomplish this. Use the Bing Maps REST Routing service to get an array of points that make up the route line. (Assuming you want to animate along a driving route). Create a timer and increment a distance by a specified amount every time it triggers. This will give you a speed, then every time the distance is increased use it to loop through all route points and calculate the distance between each point and sum them up until they exceed your current distance. hen this happens step back one place in the route point array, then set the location of your pin to this location.

Comment: I've read that blog a couple of times, but couldn't wrap my head around it. The TimerTick event isn't really explained well in the blog. I'll try to build something using your explanation! Thank you!